# Need to get all <img> from the_content(); in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've recently just imported all of the content from a blogger site into wordpress and I need to tidy things up a bit.

I'm working inside the single.php and I want to get each `<a><img src=""/></a>` from `the_content();`. My php is a little shoddy at best.

I understand this gets me the first image of the post, but I need something similar, one that gets me all the images (not featured images) from `the_content();`.

```
function catch_that_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $first_img = $matches[1][0];

    if(empty($first_img)) {
        $first_img = "/path/to/default.png";
    }
    return $first_img;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the PHP's native DOMDocument object. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

You would take your content and load it into a DOMDocument via `loadHTML()`.  THen you can use `getElementsByTagName()` to get all the images.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($post->post_content);
$images = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Comment: FYI: trying to parse html with regex is usually not a good thing. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/498699

Comment: It seems to be returning with Null: updated question

Answer (score 2):

Trivial task for [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($post->post_content);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img)
    $img->attributes['src'] = '/path/to/default.png'; // or whatever you want to do
return $doc->saveHTML();
```

You need to watch out though, `saveHTML()` might add missing tags around your structure.

Comment: Ha, great, that's what I like to hear.

Comment: I had to modify this a bit for it to work: `$img->setAttribute('src', '/path/to/default.png');`