# PHP/Wordpress - Get the width/height attributes of a <img>

Tags: php, wordpress, image, height, width

I'm currently working on a Wordpress-based new version of my website, and there is a function I'd like to add without knowing how to.

So maybe you could help me... I hope so!

I'd like to add a filter on the_content, that works for each `<img ...>` within.
This function would get the width and height attributes (e.g. `<img src="image.jpg" **height="120" width="300**" alt="test" />`) in variables (`$thisWidth`, `$thisHeight`).

Then I'd compare width & height of each image to know if it's a landscape or portait format, and add a corresponding class. Easy: `if($width > $height) { ... } else { ... }`

I'm not used to work with `regex` and so, so this is why I need your help.
My skills allows me to write the base of the function, but no more:

```
function imgClass($content) {

   /* for each '<img ....>' Loop ? */
   $thisWidth = /* get html width attribute */;
   $thisHeight = /* get html height attribute */;
   if($width > $height) { /* add class='landscape' */ } else { /* add class='portrait' */ }
   return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','imgClass');
```

I'd be so thankful to anybody being able to help me...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861875/need-to-get-all-img-from-the-content-in-wordpress

Comment: A side note - when you define your own function in theme's `functions.php` file (or if you develop a plugin), *ALWAYS* give a unique name to it and wrap the function in `if(!function_exists('your_function_name'))` in order to avoid function names conflicts with other plugins/Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys!

Mindreater > It is! Didn't find it when I searched before posting my question.

But I don't understand how I can add a class to the <img> after the comparison.

And there is not need to do a loop for each image? The function is applied as a loop to each image, one by one?

Bodi0 > Didn't know it, very helpful to avoid internal conflicts!

Answer (score 0):

here is a good example, using javascript

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="planets" src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" usemap="#planetmap">



<p>Click the button to display the coordinates for the "planets.gif" area.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("planets").width;
    var y = document.getElementById("planets").height;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but I'd like to avoid using javascript.